# Accessing Server Tags inside Javascript in MVC project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, server-variables, server-tags

I'd like to use some server tags inside a Javascript function:

```
<%=Model.HtmlProperty%>
```

In the past I have stored this value in a hidden input field, but when a property contains HTML you get problems with special characters such as quotes.  I would like to avoid having to encode and decode in the controller to avoid problems with special characters.

Rick Strahl has a [couple](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/252178.aspx) [posts](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/259442.aspx) on this problem in a web forms project, but I'm looking for an elegant solution for an MVC project.

**UPDATE**:  Robert Harvey's answer below suggests to encode the html.  Again, that *isn't what I want to do*.  Ultimately, I'm trying to inject html script into an fckeditor instance.  This must be done in javascript.  I'm trying to figure out how to access the value of `<%=Model.HtmlProperty%>` inside javascript without storing encoded text in a hidden input element.

Comment: You can store it inside hidden div content; inside JS variable; as JS function that returns a string; just encode it properly. You can't access server tags from JS; JS works in browser and can access JS variables, HTML fields, cookies... choose yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I was hoping to do - using server tags inside javascript - is not possible.  I had been storing the string inside a hidden input element, and as per queen3's comment, it seems that I will have to keep on doing what I have been doing all along.  Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Rick Strahl's post, and changing the calling signature a bit, the function for encoding a javascript string (after changing it into an extension method for the Html class) looks like this:

```
public static string EncodeJsString(this HtmlHelper h, string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("\"");
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\"':
                sb.Append("\\\"");
                break;
            case '\\':
                sb.Append("\\\\");
                break;
            case '\b':
                sb.Append("\\b");
                break;
            case '\f':
                sb.Append("\\f");
                break;
            case '\n':
                sb.Append("\\n");
                break;
            case '\r':
                sb.Append("\\r");
                break;
            case '\t':
                sb.Append("\\t");
                break;
            default:
                int i = (int)c;
                if (i < 32 || i > 127)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X04}", i);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    sb.Append("\"");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Which should allow you to call it like this:

```
<%= Html.EncodeJsString(Model.HtmlProperty) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, this won't allow me to use a server tag inside javascript. I'm trying to inject html code into fckeditor without having to store encoded html inside of a hidden input html element.  Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLHelper to write your script on the fly..

```
public static string WriteLightboxScript(this HtmlHelper helper, string galleryName)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("script");
            builder.MergeAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            builder.SetInnerText("$(function() {$('a[rel=" + galleryName + "]').lightBox();});");
            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
```